# Determining which element is source of inherited height

Tags: html, css

Sometimes I find it difficult to determine the parent element that a descendant is inheriting its height from, when the descendant is set to `height:100%`.  Does Chrome Dev Tools or any browser show this information?  (I must be missing something obvious)

Comment: See "computed" tab on chrome inspector to see these informations :)

Comment: So when I look at the "height" style under the "computed" tab, I see the inherited classes listed.  But I do not see a reference to the ancestral element that is actually providing the inheritance.  One has to explore upward looking for matching classes... no?

Comment: For looking inheritance, you can stay in the "styles" tab and scroll down :)

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome you have it in "Elements" panel >> "Styles" tab.

When you scroll down, you will see something like this

[picture of inherited style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQSof.png)

At the bottom you can also style pseudo elements.

It works similar in opera and firefox.